# How to change the color of a glyphish iPhone icon?

Tags: iphone, adobe-photoshop, graphics

Can anyone tell me how I would go about changing the color of a glyphish icon using Photoshop CS4?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the icon and add additional info stating which colour you would like to change etc.

Comment: Check out this script to batch convert icons to any color. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/unable-to-duplicate-use-of-glyphish-icons-in-jquery-navbar-demo

Answer (score 12):

I'm the guy behind Glyphish. There's a few ways to change the color. Easiest is go to Edit > Fill, then choose Color from the first dropdown, ensure *Preserve Transparency* is checked, and hit OK.

Happy to explain in more detail; let me know if you get that to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I recently bought your glyphish pro icon set. (Lovely work and a very nice price - well done!) Perhaps surprising for someone with your experience, but I actually searched for quite a while on how to add color. At first I thought it should be done programmatically - but while possible, that's a pain if you don't really need the color to vary. But the first place I looked was for a link on the glyphish site. A minimalist FAQ with this kind of info wouldn't hurt. I think a lot of your customers are probably coders who are design-clueless like me. Just a suggestion.

Comment: oh, and could you add some more details here in the meantime please? E.g. What's the Photoshop workflow for this: How do I isolate the icon I want to color in the psd; How do I then produce the PNG versions (normal and retina); Is it better to work with the PSD or directly with the PNG? Is it better to try to color the white or the grey version, ...

Answer (score 2):

Using ImageMagick via the console :

```
for f in *.png; 
     do convert $f -fuzz 100% -fill '#55E2FF' -opaque white "cyan/$fil"; 
done
```

---

The example above colors all *white* icons to **cyan** and puts them in the appropriate subfolder.

---

P.S. I do know this is an answer to an old topic, but hopefully someone will benefit from that. ;)